# Performance: searching through Map Object

Tags: performance, dictionary, hashset

I've got a Map (Integer,String). Is there a fast way to search through the String values of the map?

Comment: HashMap use Hashfunction to hash your keys not values...searching for a particular key will take O(1) amount of time in hashmap.for your requirement you can skip keys and values

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that you are using Java and your `Map` is an `HashMap<Integer, String>`:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(); //create the map (in this case an HashMap) of the desired type
```

To add some values in the map use: `map.put(desiredIntegerKey, desiredStringValue);`

Then you can iterate on the string values collection in this way:

```
for (String value : map.values()) { //loop to iterate over all the string values contained by the map
    //do something with the variable value
    if (value.contains("something")) {
        //this is just an example if you are searching for a string in the map containing a specific sub-string
    }
}
```

So basically you can search or do whatever you want with the string values.

Alternatively you can also iterate on the collection of the keys value, if you need also the have a reference to the keys:

```
for (Integer key : map.keySet()) { //loop to iterate over all the integer keys contained by the map
    String value = map.get(key);
    if (value.contains("something")) {
        //in this case you have also the value of the integer key stored in the key variable
    }
}
```